# Failed to install ubuntu on QEMU for macOS host

Tags: macos, ubuntu, virtual-machine, qemu

I am new to QEMU virtual machine.

I am now installing ubuntu16.04 on QEMU virtual machine for macOS catalina host by following this tutorial:
https://graspingtech.com/ubuntu-desktop-18.04-virtual-machine-macos-qemu/

However, after I command to launch QEMU with ubuntu ISO, I didn't get into the ubuntu installer.

I command:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 \
  -m 2048 \
  -vga virtio \
  -show-cursor \
  -usb \
  -device usb-tablet \
  -enable-kvm \
  -cdrom  /Users/my_path/QEMU/ubuntu-16.04.6-desktop-amd64.iso \
  -drive file=/Users/mt_path/QEMU/ubuntu-16.04.6-live-server-amd64.qcow2,if=virtio \
  -accel hvf \
  -cpu host
```

, but I got `No bootable device` on QEMU

[No bootalbe device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/61OoO.png)

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Checkout that the CDROM ISO is also enabled to boot from. Add parameter `-boot d` to boot the first virtual CD-ROM drive.

Answer (score 0):

You should also specify a boot drive when launching the vm

Running `qemu-system-x86_64 --help` on my machine yields this regarding the boot order:

```
-boot [order=drives][,once=drives][,menu=on|off]
      [,splash=sp_name][,splash-time=sp_time][,reboot-timeout=rb_time][,strict=on|off]
                'drives': floppy (a), hard disk (c), CD-ROM (d), network (n)
                'sp_name': the file's name that would be passed to bios as logo picture, if menu=on
                'sp_time': the period that splash picture last if menu=on, unit is ms
                'rb_timeout': the timeout before guest reboot when boot failed, unit is ms
```

In your case that should be `-boot c` for `hard disk (c)`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved.
That is because I made some dummy to the .qcow2 file.
I tried to re-make the .qcow2 and re-download the .iso, and it works.